# Как отключить кнопки?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Я хочу добавить кнопки под сообщениями моего бота так, чтобы после нажатия они деактивировались!
Я сделал всё согласно документации `button.disabled = True` однако это не работает :_(
Помогите пожалуйста! Буду сильно благодарен <3

[image: https://i.imgur.com/jscShqN.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UiuZuLJ.png]

```
class Buttons(disnake.ui.View):
def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
    super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
@disnake.ui.button(label="",style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
async def great_button(self,button:disnake.ui.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
    button.disabled=True
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"Спасибо за ваш отзыв!", delete_after=5)
    requests.get("ip сервера")
@disnake.ui.button(label="", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
async def bad_button(self, button:disnake.ui.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
    button.disabled = True
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"Спасибо за ваш отзыв!", delete_after=5)
    requests.get("ip сервера")
```

Comment: вероятнее всего, отключенные кнопки надо снова добавлять во `View` и при изменении сообщения передавать `view` с измененными кнопками